# LocationManager versus FusedLocationProvider

Tags: android

Currently we use LocationManager to get GPS updates every few seconds, we use it for high accuracy updates.

Besides, we also want to get location coordinates every 5 minutes irrespective of GPS state (turned on/off), we really ignore accuracy of location in this scenario. We want to use FusedLocationProvider for this operation.

Can both locationmanager and fusedlocationprovider co-exist in the same app; if so, are there any reliability issues?

Comment: You can have both, google make recommendations in FusedLocation, and both can give you updates with a GPS turned off (using WiFi or other sensors) https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider/

Comment: FusedLocationProvider also uses cached location which will be provided even to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY clients. As of now, the first update of location works fine but once i remove callback from the provider (to stop updates), all hell breaks loose. The next time i try to update, it's just the cache unless there are about 10-20 requests within a very small time.